# How to run a C# application at Windows startup (update)?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, startup

I want to run a C# application at startup. I used this code, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453998/c-sharp-run-application-minimized-at-windows-startup):

```
private void SetStartup(bool enable)
    {
        string runKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

        RegistryKey startupKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(runKey);

        if (enable)
        {
            if (startupKey.GetValue("ZanNews") == null)
            {
                startupKey.Close();
                startupKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
                startupKey.SetValue("ZanNews", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
                startupKey.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            startupKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
            startupKey.DeleteValue("ZanNews", false);
            startupKey.Close();
        }
    }
```

Although the entry appears in the registry and the Task Manager, the program doesn't start with Windows.

Before asking this question, I did prior research on StackOverflow and none of the solutions and code snippets proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-application-at-windows-startup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762945/run-c-sharp-application-at-windows-startup) worked. Either I got security and access error messages or the registry was written, but the program refused to start with the operating system. I see, however, that the questions above were asked in 2010 and 2011 and I am thinking that things changed since then.

Is there a way to make a program run at startup? I have Windows 10, Home Edition, version 1803 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed on Windows 10 April 2018 Update.

*Later edit:* other information:

1. The value of `Application.ExecutablePath` is `C:\\Users\\alexz\\OneDrive\\Programe\\C#/ZanScore/ZanScore/bin/Debug/ZanNews.exe"`;
2. I tried removing the "#" character, with no luck;
3. Screenshot of Registry Editor: [image: Screenshot]
4. Screenshot of Task Manager (in Romanian): [image: Screenshot]

Comment: How exactly are you **running** `SetStartup`?

Comment: Please also include a screenshot in your question of a command prompt which has run `dir` in `C:\\Users\\alexz\\OneDrive\\Programe\\C#/ZanScore/ZanScore/bin/Debug/` (i.e. prove to us the folder exists, and the executable in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some research, I found that it's a much better way to create a shortcut and place it in the `Startup` folder. More details are presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391923/placing-a-shortcut-in-users-startup-folder-to-start-with-windows) and the code (which works and solves the problem) is:

```
        WshShell wshShell = new WshShell();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut;
        string startUpFolderPath =
          Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);

        // Create the shortcut
        shortcut =
          (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(
            startUpFolderPath + "\\" +
            Application.ProductName + ".lnk");

        shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
        shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        shortcut.Description = "Launch My Application";
        // shortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\App.ico";
        shortcut.Save();
```

To be able to use the above code, you need to include the `IWshRuntimeLibrary` namespace and add the *Windows Script Host Object Model* reference to the project.

Other reference is [here](https://blog.jsinh.in/how-to-create-application-shortcut-programmatically-using-csharp/#.XG09BOgzZPZ)